# Prohibit app access in android

Tags: java, android

My question is if it's possible to create an app where the user can temporarily block several apps, so he can prohibit using an app for an optimal time?

Comment: Not with normal permissions.  Possibly with device owner permissions and DeviceManager, but you're talking about needing to own the device not a play app at that point.

Comment: What you are looking is essentially a parental control app.

Comment: ... or a **ransomware** app.

Comment: @Rotwang can you tell me what a ransomeware app is?

Comment: It's a kind of **malware** which will BREAK some functionality on your device (like you want to do). Then it will ask for money to the device owner to make the device work as it should.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've done that.

As a rough solution, if you set your 'controller' app as an accessibility app then it has the ability to monitor which apps are launched. Then you can apply your logic to determine if an app is allowed to be run at this time. If it should be blocked then you can launch a full screen overlay to block that app and show a warning/ block message instead.

Comment: Is there a setting to make it an accessibility app?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your exact intentions, but generally it is possible, of course, with some limitations - many applications for parental control do this. You need to check out `AccessibilityService` documentation to dive deeper. [This test project](https://github.com/syndarin/AccessibilityServiceDemo) may help you to understand some basic concepts - in it I demonstrated how you could block applications, which use `INTERNET` permission.

Comment: General question according to that: is it only possible for additional apps or for system apps as well?

Comment: I didn't make comprehensive research about that, but, for example, it works for default "Settings" application, so I believe will work for the rest too.

Comment: Is your test an android program that I can run?

Comment: You can compile the project given